# RXJS casting Event to KeyboardEvent inside pipe operator

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to add a keydown event and cast the type of the parameter from Event to KeyboardEvent, but I receive the following TS error.

```js
fromEvent(document, "keydown")
  .pipe<KeyboardEvent, KeyboardEvent>(
    filter((event) => event.code === "F5"),
    tap((event) => event.preventDefault())
  )
  .subscribe((ev) => {
    console.log(ev);
  });
```

but I get the following error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<Event>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Event, KeyboardEvent>'.
  Type 'Observable<Event>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<KeyboardEvent>'.
    Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'KeyboardEvent': altKey, charCode, 
code, ctrlKey, and 17 more.
```

Did anyone face this issue?

Answer (score 5):

`fromEvent` is also generic.

```
fromEvent<KeyboardEvent>(document, "keydown") // ...
```